# How to figure out which (potentially uninstalled) port provides a command in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, binary-files, freebsd-ports

`make search name=X` and `make search key=Y` don't seem to find command names reliably, especially not if they aren't mentioned in the port's description. In Debian-based systems there's `apt-file` which finds commands (and more) in the list of binary sources of the system's package manager.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this from command line, but searching [FreshPorts](http://www.freshports.org/) is a good way. On the search page, if you set the search to "Under a pathname", that may find what you're looking for, or using the Google search box at the top may help too.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /usr/ports -name pkg-plist -maxdepth 3 | xargs grep command
```

But this fails if the port uses AUTOPLIST (it generates its installed files during build)